# How to check if Object keys are in Array filtered by Array key?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with an Angular 2 Ionic app -

Is there a way I can filter all persons by age in my personsArr and then find if any key in my personObj matches a personArr name and return a boolean?

I have an example array like:

```
personsArr = [{
        "name": "Ram",
        "email": "ram@gmail.com",
        "age": 23
    },
    {
        "name": "peter",
        "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
        "age": 23
    },
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "age": 33
    },
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "email": "bob32@gmail.com",
        "age": 41
    }
]
```

and an object like this

```
personObj = {
    "peter": "helper",
    "Ram": "helper",
    "Bob": "helper"
}
```

How can I filter personsArr by age and then check if any key from personObj matches person name?

Pretty sure I can just do this with a loop, but is there a better way?

Appreciate any help or advise.

Comment: What are expected results to store the boolean? Please also show us what you tried with your loop approach

Comment: What do you mean with "filter by age"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this, with filter and some. You filter by your condition and then check for matches on the object. Hope this helps.

```js
const personsArr = [{
    "name": "Ram",
    "email": "ram@gmail.com",
    "age": 23
    }, {
        "name": "peter",
        "email": "shyam23@gmail.com",
        "age": 23
    }, {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@gmail.com",
        "age": 33
    }, {
        "name": "Bob",
        "email": "bob32@gmail.com",
        "age": 41
    }];

const personObj = { "Ram": "helper", "Bob": "helper" };

const personObj2 = { "Ram2": "helper", "Bob2": "helper" };

const checkArr = (age, arr, obj) => arr.filter((f) => f.age > age).some((d) => obj[d.name]);

console.log('Should be true');
console.log(checkArr(30, personsArr, personObj));
console.log('Should be false');
console.log(checkArr(30, personsArr, personObj2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
// Filter by age
const legalAge = 18 // for example
const boolean = personsArr
    // Actual filtering 
    .filter(p => p.age > legalAge)
    // Check if there is any `name` in personsArr matching any key in personObj
    .some(p =>
        Object.keys(personObj).some(pk => pk === p.name)
    )

// Sort by age (maybe you meant this instead of filtering)
personsArr.sort((a, b) => a.age > b.age ? 1 : -1)
const boolean2 = personsArr.some(p =>
    Object.keys(personObj).some(pk => pk === p.name)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly then you need something like this:

```
const isFound = personsArr.some((item) => item.age > 30 && personObj.includes(item.name));
```

Of course `item.age > 30` should be replaced with you filtering criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you loop yourself or not, there is looping involved. The simplest answer is probably to use `Array.filter`.

```
personsArr.filter((val) => val.age === age && Object.keys(roles).indexOf(val.name) > -1);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
const personsArr = [
    { "name": "Ram", "email": "ram@gmail.com", "age": 23 },
    { "name": "peter", "email": "shyam23@gmail.com", "age": 23 },
    { "name": "John", "email": "john@gmail.com", "age": 33 },
    { "name": "Bob", "email": "bob32@gmail.com", "age": 41 }
];

const personObj = { "peter": "helper", "Ram": "helper", "Bob": "helper" };

function filter(age: number, roles: { [name: string]: string }) {
    const keys = Object.keys(roles);
    return personsArr.filter((val) => val.age === age && keys.indexOf(val.name) > -1);
}

// 0: Object { name: "Ram", email: "ram@gmail.com", age: 23 }
​// 1: Object { name: "peter", email: "shyam23@gmail.com", age: 23 }
console.log(filter(23, personObj));

// 0: Object { name: "Bob", email: "bob32@gmail.com", age: 41 }
console.log(filter(41, personObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var personsArr = [    
{"name":"Ram", "email":"ram@gmail.com", "age":23},    
{"name":"peter", "email":"shyam23@gmail.com", "age":23},  
{"name":"John", "email":"john@gmail.com", "age":33},    
{"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "age":41}   
];

var personObj = {"peter":"helper","Ram":"helper", "Bob":"helper"}

var newPersonsArr = personsArr.filter((person) => person.age<30);
var check = false;
for(var key in personObj) {
  newPersonsArr.map((person) => {
  if(person.name === key){
   check = true
  }
  });
}


console.log(check);
```

Comment: As you are already using `Array.filter` for age you could check the name condition at the same time, thus reducing the amount of looping.

Comment: This works - Is there anyway to break the loop after the first match? When I console log I am getting many additional loops of true.